# Usage of socket.io and express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am new to Node js and just now I come across through socket.io and express js, I want to know the difference between them or the relation between them. I am having some small codes that was used for the chat application

In the nodeClient.js

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:8080' );

$( "#messageForm" ).submit( function() {

var nameVal = $( "#nameInput" ).val();
var msg = $( "#messageInput" ).val();
alert("msg");
socket.emit( 'message', { name: nameVal, message: msg } );

// Ajax call for saving datas
$.ajax({
url: "./ajax/insertNewMessage.php",
type: "POST",
data: { name: nameVal, message: msg },
success: function(data) {

}
});

return false;
});

socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
var actualContent = $( "#messages" ).html();
alert(actualContent);
var newMsgContent = '<li> <strong>' + data.name + '</strong> : ' + data.message + '</li>';
var content = newMsgContent + actualContent;

$( "#messages" ).html( content );
});
```

and in the nodeServer.js

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server );

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( client ) {
    console.log( "New client !" );

    client.on( 'message', function( data ) {
        console.log( 'Message received ' + data.name + ":" + data.message );

        //client.broadcast.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
        io.sockets.emit( 'message', { name: data.name, message: data.message } );
    });
});

server.listen( 8080 );
```

Now, coming to the ponit of my doubt

in the nodeServer.js file, I have

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server );
```

I can observe there is some relation here between socket and express, Can anyone please explain me the relation and the usage of those two.

This will help me to move further into more node js applications

thanks!

Comment: There is no relation between the two. You can use them separate or together. I suggest you read about what they are on their respective websites http://expressjs.com and http://socket.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the nodeServer.js, you can declare or call the socket.io or express. In the nodeClient.js. You will run those functions. What I can say is, Using socket.io, we get data from the database and it will store with it and displays when the page loads even before PHP loads the same. So, we can call nodejs is faster.